# Accessing nested route parameter from parent route/template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I have a nested route that behaves similarly to a less-nested version of itself:

```
/code/class/MyFile.java
/code/coverage/:coverageId/class/MyFile.java
```

Somewhat self-explanatory, but the `coverage` route decorates the page with some additional highlighting/details that are not present in the "normal" version.

However, my `code` template defines a sidebar that includes a navigation tree to access other code files. When viewing a `/coverage/` page, I would like for the sidebar to display the links differently, ensuring that the nested route is maintained when clicking around.

**My Problem:**

I can't seem to find a way to access the `:coverageId` in the `code` route or template to modify the way the links are displayed. My code route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    console.log('Coverage ID: ' + params.coverageId);
      ...
```

Prints `undefined`. This seems to make sense since it's a *child* parameter, which is "out of scope"?

**My Incorrect Solution:**

I tried this in my `class` route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    var parentModel = this.modelFor('code');
    parentModel.coverageId = params.coverageId;
    ...
```

Which, in my `code.hbs` template:

```
{{#if model.coverageId}}
  {{#link-to 'code.coverage.class' model.coverageId fileName}}{{fileName}}
  {{/link-to}}
{{else}}
  {{#link-to 'code.class' fileName}}{{fileName}}{{/link-to}}
{{/if}}
```

Actually works! The link is produced properly when viewing the `coverage` route.

**However:** While I can right-click any of these links to open them in a separate tab successfully, if I just regularly click them, I receive an error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `coverageId` property (of [object Object]) to `425988`
```

But of course, I can't use `parentModel.set('coverageId', params.coverageId);`, because it fails with:

```
TypeError: parentModel.set is not a function
```

**So!** How can I either (1) examine the nested route parameters in the parent (`code`) route, or (2) properly inject the known value (`:coverageId`) from a child route *into* the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of that `.set` is not a function error by using global [`Ember.set`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_set).

So, instead of:

```
parentModel.coverageId = params.coverageId;
```

Try:

```
Ember.set(parentModel, 'coverageId', params.coverageId);
```

Comment: Thank you - that works perfectly. I *expected* something like that to be available, but stumbled upon the wrong documentation, which led me to believe there wasn't a 3-arg `set()` function: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_set Still getting used to the Ember docs/class structure.